# Javascript doesn't hide tr element

Tags: javascript, html-table, visible

I am trying hide a row of a table. Here is the table row:

```
<input id="CheckboxDamage" onchange="ChangeDmgExpVisibility()" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
<table style="width: 100%;">
***some other rows***
<tr id="dmg">
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDamageExplanation" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadDamage" runat="server" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my js:

```
function ChangeDmgExpVisibility() {
        var txtbox = document.getElementById('dmg');
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('CheckboxDamage');

        if (checkbox.checked)
            txtbox.style.visibility = "visible";
        else
            txtbox.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

I also tried:

```
function ChangeDmgExpVisibility() {
        var txtbox = document.getElementById('dmg');
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('CheckboxDamage');

        if (checkbox.checked)
            txtbox.style.display = "block";
        else
            txtbox.style.display = "none";
    }
```

None of them gave any result. Any advice ?

Comment: It is working https://jsfiddle.net/tnw5o9d1/. Do you have any error in your console?

Comment: I am not sure this is the problem cause I get pop-up when I write an alert inside the method so onchange does work

Comment: If you have multiple `divs` with the same `id` of `dmg`, it will not work.

Comment: Are you entering the function ? Did you try to print your elements in the console to see if you get the elements with this code ?

Comment: ok... you cannot have multiple elements with the same id. you should use a class attribute instead. Ids are suposed to be unique

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing/Hiding Table Rows with Javascript - can do with ID - how to do with Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518035/showing-hiding-table-rows-with-javascript-can-do-with-id-how-to-do-with-clas)

Comment: The code you gave should work. It must be something else.

Comment: Only this tr has the 'dmg' id. When I use a try-catch it tells me something like 'Cannot read propert 'checked' of null', but I can't see why it is null

Comment: If you changed `<tr id="dmg">` to `<tr class="dmg">` and used `getElementsByClassName` then checking the box would hide all the table rows. Each table row needs a unique identifier.

Comment: Are you running this code after the DOM get ready? windows.onload?

Answer (score 0):

You may have called the function before defining it. It works fine in this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cv29c702/

The code looks like this:

```
<script>
function ChangeDmgExpVisibility() {
        var txtbox = document.getElementById('dmg');
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('CheckboxDamage');

        if (checkbox.checked)
            txtbox.style.visibility = "visible";
        else
            txtbox.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>

<input id="CheckboxDamage" onchange="ChangeDmgExpVisibility()" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
<table style="width: 100%;">
***some other rows***
<tr id="dmg">
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDamageExplanation" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server">hello there</asp:TextBox>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadDamage" runat="server" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I just made sure to define the function before calling it in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all support but nothing worked and it is really strange since it is working well in jsfiddle.net and not working in my code. I used a different, simple way and solved the problem:

```
var see = true;
    function ChangeDmgExpVisibility() {
        var txtbox = document.getElementById('dmg');

        if (see) {
            txtbox.style.visibility = "hidden";
            see = false;
        }

        else {
            txtbox.style.visibility = "visible";
            see = true;
        }

    }
```

Like I said, I still don't know why my first method didn't work but this works without a problem.